sp_send_dbmail not working but send test e-mail for database mail working
I set up database mail on a SQL Server.
When I send a test e-mail form SSMS it works.
When I try to send an email using msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail via the query window  I get:
Mail (Id: xx) queued.  but email not sent.
log of email that sent via test e-mail form SSMS (sent successfully):



Profile ID
Recipients
Copy Recipients
Blind Copy Recipients
Subject
From Address
Reply To
Body
Body Format
Importance
Sensitivity
File Attachments
Attachment Encoding
Query
Execute Query Database
Attach Query Result as File
Query Result Header
Query Result Width
Query Result Separator
Exclude Query Output
Append Query Error
Send Request Date
Send Request User
Sent Account ID
Sent Status
Sent Date
Last Mod Date
Last Mod User




17
myemail@gmail.com
NULL
NULL
Subject
NULL
NULL
Body
TEXT
NORMAL
NORMAL
NULL
MIME
NULL
0
1
256
0
0
0
0
2024-10-10 12:10:02.467
myuser
11
1
2024-10-10 12:10:08.000
2024-10-10 12:10:08.900
sa



log of email that sent via query (queued but not sent):
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients = 'myemail@gmail.com',
    @subject = 'Subject',
    @body = 'Body',
    @profile_name = 'MyProfile'




Profile ID
Recipients
Copy Recipients
Blind Copy Recipients
Subject
From Address
Reply To
Body
Body Format
Importance
Sensitivity
File Attachments
Attachment Encoding
Query
Execute Query Database
Attach Query Result as File
Query Result Header
Query Result Width
Query Result Separator
Exclude Query Output
Append Query Error
Send Request Date
Send Request User
Sent Account ID
Sent Status
Sent Date
Last Mod Date
Last Mod User




17
myemail@gmail.com
NULL
NULL
Subject
NULL
NULL
Body
TEXT
NORMAL
NORMAL
NULL
MIME
NULL
0
1
256
0
0
0
0
2024-10-10 12:01:15.897
myuser
NULL
0
NULL
2024-10-10 12:01:15.897
sa



I checked the sysmail_faileditems, and there are no error logs related to what I sent...
Why it is working via test e-mail form SSMS but not via query?

Have you checked the permissions of the user sending the mail to run "sp_send_dbmail"? EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_profileaccount_sp

@mbielsa I thought it might be a permissions-related issue, but I don't know what to check. The sysmail_help_profileaccount_sp query simply returns the profile name and the account name.

You can also check by adding @from_address=myprofile@sender.com to sp_send_dbmail. That way, if that doesn't work, you'll get a more specific error. And also SELECT      dp.name AS principalName,      dpr.name AS roleName FROM      msdb.sys.database_principals dp  JOIN msdb.sys.database_role_members drm ON dp.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id  JOIN msdb.sys.database_principals dpr ON drm.role_principal_id = dpr.principal_id WHERE      dpr.name = 'MyProfileRoleName'

@mbielsa
Adding from_address didn’t change much... I still don’t see any error log.  (the mail is queued but not sent)
Regarding the query you wrote, I get the following results:
MyUserLogin - DatabaseMailUserRole and
NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT - DatabaseMailUserRole

Did you try add your user to role member? USE msdb; EXEC sp_addrolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole', 'myuser'

@mbielsa yep and I can see it listed with your query.

To increase the logging level EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_configure_sp 'LoggingLevel', 'Verbose' and check the connection for example telnet smtp.server.com 25
